# ASP.Net CSS MasterPages Main Content Area Not Auto Increasing With <Span> Tags

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a master page which creates a ContentPlaceHolder for each page where my main content/information goes. Around this i have created a div tag called main.

```
<div id="Main">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

#Main
{
    background-color:White;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    margin: 0px 100px 10px 100px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

So essentialy the contentplaceholder is a nice white space where information can go into. If i go onto a page and write some stuff into the content with p tags the white space auto expands.

However i'm trying to create 2 span tags on the same line where i can add pane on the left and a datagrid on the right. but for the moment ive filled these span tags with just text. However the white space does not auto expand, ive changed the height of the span tag but it goes over into the footer. Any ideas?

```
<asp:Content ID="SearchContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<span id="SearchLeftPanel" class="SearchDivs">
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
leftleftleftleft
</span>

<span id="SearchRightPanel" class="SearchDivs">
RightRightRightRightRightRight
RightRightRightRightRightRight
RightRightRightRightRightRight
RightRightRightRightRightRight
RightRightRightRightRightRight
RightRightRightRightRightRight
RightRightRightRightRightRight
RightRightRightRightRightRight
</span>
```

```
.SearchDivs
{
   display:inline;
}
#SearchLeftPanel
{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100px;    
}
#SearchRightPanel
{
   float:right;
   width:67%;
   height:100px;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height:100px` from your css nad give `height:auto`

If you need default height to be 100px then you can write like this

```
#SearchRightPanel
{
   float:right;
   width:67%;  
min-height:100px; 
height:auto
}
```

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/YUTTh/1/

Updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/YUTTh/2/

Comment: Hi, i did this just now, i'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Do it for both id style. check the demo in my answer

Comment: .SearchDivs
{
   display:inline;
}
#SearchLeftPanel
{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
  
}
#SearchRightPanel
{
   float:right;
   width:67%; 
   min-height:100px;
   height:auto
}
 Done it exactly like that, the text still overflows onto the footer and the white space is not expanding.

Comment: The Height changes, i can see that but the white space is not expanding :/

Comment: Sorry didnt observe tat. add overflow:auto to #main style. Check the updated demo

Comment: That seem to have worked. Is there a reason you only have height:auto; on the right panel and not on the left?

Comment: You can use your style for right and left panel if you are not worried about the auto extend for inner divs. I just added tat for trail n error